# Debian "make" error

Tags: makefile, debian, bitcoin

I'm trying to install ufasoft miner on my Debian machine, but after entering `make` it shows this message:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/ufasoft_coin-0.75'
  CXX      el/libext/bignum.o
In file included from el/libext/bignum.cpp:18:0:
./el/bignum.h: In member function ?void Ext::BigInteger::swap(Ext::BigInteger&)?:
./el/bignum.h:310:8: error: ?mpz_class? has no member named ?swap?
make[1]: *** [el/libext/bignum.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/ufasoft_coin-0.75'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) version.

For me, `ufasoft_coin-0.75` compiles fine against the latest `gmp-5.1.3` (With `--enable-cxx`)